# JQUERY :Parent selector not working

Tags: jquery, parent-child

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".lvl_0 ul").mouseover(function() {
    $(".subnav:parent > a span").addClass("subOpen");

  });

  $(".lvl_0 ul").mouseout(function() {

    $(".subnav:parent > a span").addClass("subOpen");

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tile_nav">
  <li class="lvl_0">
    <a href="#">Tile
      <span>---</span>
    </a>

    <ul class="subnav">
      <li><a href="#">XXXXX <span>---</span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">XXXXX <span>---</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>

  <li class="lvl_0"><a href="#">Tile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="lvl_0"><a href="#">Tile</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Please help, why this `:parent` selector not working with direct child. on mouse over of sub `<ul>` should add a class to `<span>` of parent `<li>`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to get the parent element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".lvl_0 ul").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).parent().children('a').addClass("subOpen");

    });

    $(".lvl_0 ul").mouseout(function () {

        $(this).parent().children('a').addClass("subOpen");
    });
});
```

You can also use [**hover**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".lvl_0 ul").hover(function () {
        $(this).parent().children('a').addClass("subOpen");
    }, function () {
        $(this).parent().children('a').removeClass("subOpen");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
To select parent in jquery you can use parent(), parents(), closest(). In which way you may like.

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".lvl_0 ul").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).parent().children('a').find('span').addClass("subOpen");

    });

    $(".lvl_0 ul").mouseout(function () {

        $(this).parent().children('a').find('span').addClass("subOpen");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

*Why your code does not work*

**[:parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/)**

> Select all elements that have at least one child node (either an element or text).

You need the parent element and elements with childnodes.

---

So either use `.closest()` or `.parent()`

```
$(' > a span',$('.subnav').closest('ul')).addClass("subOpen");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are looking for the previous sibling of the `ul` element, also use hover/mouseenter-mouseleave events

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".lvl_0 ul").hover(function () {
        $(this).prev('a').find('span').addClass("subOpen");
    }, function () {
        $(this).prev('a').find('span').removeClass("subOpen");
    });
});
```

Comment: You missed `,` between the hover functions

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the parent of the current element by using jQuery [parent method](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)
Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kugkx30q/)

```
$(this).parent().addClass("subOpen");
```